# How to clean up CSV file with columns shifted?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file of movies that I'm trying to clean up. I'm using Jupyter notebook.

It has 10,000 rows and 5 columns. Below are some sample data:

```
Movie Name      | Genre  | Date Released  | Length        | Rating      |
The Godfather   | Crime  | March 24, 1972 | 175           | R           |
The Avengers    | Action | May 5, 2012    | 143           | PG-13       |
The Dark Knight | Action | Crime          | July 18, 2008 | 152         | PG-13
```

Notice that for "The Dark Knight", since there are 2 genres, the rows get shifted to the right. I want to clean the data such that the row becomes:

```
The Dark Knight | Action, Crime | July 18, 2008 | 152 | PG-13
```

What I did is (in Jupyter notebook)

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'movies.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=0, names=['Movie Name', 'Genre', 'Date Released','Length','Rating','Extra'])

ctrCheck = 0
months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

while ctrCheck < len(df.index):
    check = str(df['Date Released'][ctrCheck])
    if any(month in check for month in months):
        replaceStr = df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Genre'] + "," + df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Date Released']
        df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Genres'] = replaceStr
        df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Date Released'] = df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Length']
        df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Length'] = df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Rating']
        df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Rating'] = df.loc[ctrCheck, 'Extra']
    ctrCheck = ctrCheck + 1

df.drop(labels='Extra', inplace=True, axis='columns')
```

Is there a better way to do this, other than iterate through the 10,000 rows?

Thanks!

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you could write your test `if any(month in check for month in ['January', 'February', ...]):`

Comment: ah, good suggestion! will do this :)

Comment: Could you provide the actual csv input that you are using instead of the formatted view of the problem? I am sure there should be support in csv read formats to read a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you're looking for a method which does not include an explicit for loop and instead use vectorized pandas methods.

We can first notice that the rows which need transformation are the rows which has a value other than Nan in the last column

Therefore i can suggest the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Name the last unnamed column
df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 5': 'Extra'})

# Save the valid lines in a different dataframe
mask = (df['Extra'].isnull())
df_valid = df[mask]

# Fix the invalid lines
# Fix the Genre
df['Genre'] = df['Genre'] + ' ' + df['Date Released']
# Shift left the columns after 'Genre'
cols = df.columns[:-1]
df.drop('Date Released', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns = cols

# Restore valid lines
df.loc[mask, :] = df_valid
```

The resulting dataframe:

```
        Movie Name         Genre  Date Released Length Rating
0    The Godfather         Crime  March 24 1972    175      R
1     The Avengers        Action     May 5 2012    143  PG-13
2  The Dark Knight  Action Crime   July 18 2008    152  PG-13
```

**Notice** This method only works if the maximum number of genres per movie is 2, which is the case if i understand correctly :)

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly :) Is it preferable to do a method like this when parsing through large amounts of data, versus using a loop? My impression is that this would be more efficient, but I could be wrong!

Comment: You are very welcome! :) I'm glad i could help you :) I'm no expert in time comparisons, and i'd love if someone could establish the claim i'm about to propose. Libraries such as numpy and especially pandas are meant to be able to work with big data and execute many manipulations and algorithms over them efficiently. These libraries were also developed by many experienced developers and algorithm developers. Due to both of these facts i would presume the methods provided by them would be *much* more efficient than something i could develop. Therefore i would say it is preferable to use them :)